# Do Paris Metro tickets expire?

Tags: trains, paris

If I purchase a 10 pack and use 4, can I expect to use the remaining tickets anytime next year?

Comment: @HankyPanky afaik a 10 pack is the type of ticket. I remember buying them with the family (of 5) when going to Paris and using them as if they're 5 returns. It's just 10 singles.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is cost in Paris Metro between Zones 1-2 & are 2016/2017 Carnet EUR 1.45 tickets still valid as new rates are EUR 1.90?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/105117/what-is-cost-in-paris-metro-between-zones-1-2-are-2016-2017-carnet-eur-1-45-ti)

Comment: @Gilles I don't think this should be closed as a duplicate. Anyone who wants the answer in the future will find it _much_ easier to read this question and its answer than the other one, which contains five paragraphs of detailed conditions.

Comment: For other cities you should not assume that they would remain valid indefinitely. In Berlin, if the price changes for a multiple package of tickets the older ones must be used by a 6-8 week period after the new price comes into effect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [website of the Paris transport company](https://www.ratp.fr/en/questions/4656/?taxo=4656), the tickets don't have an expiration date:

> Tickets purchased individually or in packages of 10 are permanently valid for single use and are issued without an expiration date. Consequently, they can always be used at a later date.

This applies to the normal Ticket T+, so if that's the one you have, you should be fine as they don't expire.

Comment: Just an additional information: I know from several cities that the tickets usually do not have expiration dates, except the ticket prices are increased. In this case the old tickets have some kind of expiration date, which is usually >6 months. Combined with drats answer I would say it is high likely that you can use the tickets anytime next year.

Comment: Paris Ticket T+ does not expire after a price increase. But the actual tickets may have problems in the machines. If so, go to a ticket counter and ask for an exchange. There are many people experiencing these problems with the machines, so they are used for it. Out of my 'new' set of four three failed.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, magnetic tickets do not expire, but they will be slowly phased-out in 2020/21...

Comment: They do not expire, but they do tend to stop working. You can/could exchange them for new ones at the ticket desks, but even the new ones did often not work for me.